# SPSS using value of one cell to call another cell

Tags: conditional-statements, spss

Below is some data:

```
    Test Day1 Day2 Score
    A 1 2 100
    B 1 3 62
    C 3 4 90
    D 2 4 20
    E 4 5 80
```

I am trying to take the values from column 'day' and 'day2' and use them to select the row number for the column score. For example for Test A I would like to find the sum of 100 and 62 because that is the values of the first and second rows of score. Test B I would like to find the sum of 100, 62 and 90.
Does anyone have any ideas on how to go about doing this? I am looking to use something similar to the indirect function in Excel? Thank You

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The trick is to convert variable "Score" as a row. Could not think of an easy way how to avoid SAVE/GET - room for improvements.

```
file handle tmp
 /name = "C:\DATA\Temp".

***.

data list free /Test (a1) Day1 (f8) Day2 (f8) Score (f8).
begin data
A 1 2 100
B 1 3 62
C 3 4 90
D 2 4 20
E 4 5 80
end data.

comp f = 1.

var wid all (12).

save out "tmp\data.sav".


***.

get "tmp\data.sav"
 /keep score.

flip.

comp f = 1.

match files
 /file "tmp\data.sav"
 /table *
 /by f
 /drop case_lbl.

comp stat = 0.
do rep var = var001 to var005
 /k = 1 to 5.
if range(k, Day1, Day2) stat = sum(stat, var).
end rep.

list Test Day1 Day2 Score stat.
```

The result:

```
Test     Day1     Day2    Score     stat

A           1        2      100      162
B           1        3       62      252
C           3        4       90      110
D           2        4       20      172
E           4        5       80      100


Number of cases read:  5    Number of cases listed:  5
```

Comment: Thank you very much, for some reason though when I try to run this it will not create display the list in the syntax editor, when I remove flip it will display however it still will have all 0s in stat?

Comment: The "list" command is optional here. Look at your data to see the result. The "flip" command is mandatory here. The code will not work without the "flip".